# Select two distinct columns from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

So, there's a site, where users add announces, on the front page there're latest announces, some users add same announces multiple times in a day, so I need a select to show only one announce by user in a day.

I need only one announce 'id' from one user('creator') in a day('date').

I tried this, but it doesn't work the way I want(it gets all columns), anyone has any ideas ?

my code:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT least(creator, date) AS creator,
    greatest(creator, date) AS date,
    title AS product_title,
    id, 
    introimg, price,
    currency, 
    city, 
    shetanxmebit, 
    publish_date
FROM mar_home_main
WHERE introimg!="" AND publish=1 AND visible=1
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Which announcement do you want to take incase there are 5 and two of them are duplicates? a simple input and expected output would be helpful

Comment: You know that `DISTINCT` is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows?

Comment: You have to use `GROUP BY` with `MAX` or `MIN` instead of `DISTINCT`

Comment: wrong use of `DISTINCT`. Try to formulate the query using `GROUP BY`, along with `MIN/MAX` on date value.

Comment: Apart from distinct, your least() and greatest() use too seem to be wrong as it will work on same kind of dataset, here one is id and another is date, so result returned will be wrong.

Comment: thanks, everyone, I tried group by and it worked well, weird is that, I tried the same code before and it didn't work lol

Comment: It's considered good style to use standard SQL where possible. For string literals this is the single quote `'` and for unequality it's `<>`. Hence `WHERE introimg <> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at `[GROUP_CONCAT()]`. It may be one of workaround for your solutions. Click [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) for details about it.

Answer (score 0):

so, after reading comments and editing my code, this one worked for me

```
'SELECT id, creator, date, title AS product_title, introimg,
                      price, currency, city, shetanxmebit, publish_date
               FROM mar_home_main
               WHERE introimg!="" AND publish=1 AND visible=1
               GROUP BY creator, date
               ORDER BY publish_date DESC
               LIMIT 20';
```

Comment: You group by creator and date, but you are using no aggregate functions such as MIN and MAX. This means when there are several records for a creator and date, you pick the values arbitrarily from these records, i.e. one of the prices, one of the currencies, etc. It is not even guaranteed that the values are picked from the same record, so if you have 50 USD in one record and 20 EUR in another you could end up with 20 USD (although this is very unlikely to happen). Same with publish_date you sort by; this can be the first or last or any other for the creator and date.

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause but no aggregating functions. This invariably turns out to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to use a sub query to get the latest record for each group of records, then join that back to your main table

```
SELECT a.id, 
    a.creator, 
    a.date, 
    a.title AS product_title, 
    a.introimg,
    a.price, 
    a.currency, 
    a.city, 
    a.shetanxmebit, 
    a.publish_date
FROM mar_home_main a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT creator, MAX(date) AS latest_date
    FROM mar_home_main
    WHERE introimg!="" 
    AND publish=1 AND 
    visible=1
    GROUP BY creator
) sub0
ON a.creator = sub0.creator
ON a.date = sub0.latest_date
WHERE introimg!="" 
AND publish=1 
AND visible=1
ORDER BY publish_date DESC
LIMIT 20
```